# Vue.js passing props to a child of dynamic component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent dynamic component `Forms.vue` with 3 child components: `form1`,  `form2`, `form3`. I try to pass Props to the `form2` like this:

```
<forms source="/api/data" title="form2"/>
```

in the `form2` component, I try to use Axios to make a post to the `source` URL but it doesn't work: `this.source` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Can you share the component definition? Have you defined the props?

Comment: Can you show us the code of a child component where it works and one where it doesn't?

Comment: user vue bindings - :source and :title

Comment: @user2968356 in the child component form2 when i use exios.get(this.source).then(function(reponse){......}).catch(function(error){.......})
the browser console show an error because the segment of url that has to be populated by this.source show 'undefined'

Comment: Without showing us your component code, it's very hard to tell you what is wrong with your component code.  If you're having a problem with `form2`, you need to show us the definition of that component (at a minimum).

Comment: Have you declare the props "source" in your forms component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i used this.source in the form2 instead of this.$parent.source to get the props, I thought that by passing the props to the **Forms** component tag it will be accessible in all child components.